# How to expand the vector potential using spherical waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

In electromagnetic field theory, the  vector potential is,
$$\boldsymbol{A}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\iiint_{V_{1}}\boldsymbol{J}(\boldsymbol{x}')\frac{\exp(-j\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{r})}{r}dV$$
where
$$\boldsymbol{r}=\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}',\ \ \ \ \ \ r=|\boldsymbol{r}|$$

I remembe there is a formula can direct expand the following formula using spherical wave?

$$\frac{\exp(-j\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{r})}{r}$$

who knows the name of that that formula?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-wave_expansion)? Or possibly [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation)?

Comment: Thanks. But it is not exactly what I remember.